# Usage of Substring in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand the usage of Substring query in mysql
Here is the query that i tried.

```
select substr('Beautiful',-5) from dual; //output tiful
```

Is it that when we are giving a negative value, the count is done from the last character..

At the same time when i give the following query

```
select substr('Beautiful',-5,2) from dual; // outputs ti
```

Is it that when we are giving a negative value, the count is done from the last character and displays the values 5 and 6 i.e (t & i)..

The problem arises when i the following query

```
select substr('Beautiful',-5,-2) from dual; // outputs <blank>
```

I was actually expecting the output as "ut". ;  can anyone explain me what is happening here, Is my assessment for the above two queries correct ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL 5.x, for function `SUBSTRING(str,pos,len)` , 3rd parameter `len` is a non-negative integer > 0. Any other value will result in empty string.

> If `len` is less than 1, the result is the empty string.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: So, when i give a negative value to "pos" field then, is it counting from the last character of the sting?